# React useState value not updated in ref callback

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ref, react-functional-component, use-state

I have a functional component called `SignUp` it uses google recaptcha to secure the signup form.

`Signup` creates a ref pointing to the `Recaptcha` component and declares a callback function `onResolved` that points to a function method `onRecaptchaResolved`

The problem is that when `onRecaptchaResolved` is called after Recaptcha execution the value of our input is not the lastest state but the initial value set by `useState`
in our case `"hi"`

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import Recaptcha from 'react-google-invisible-recaptcha';

const Input = styled.input``

function SignUp({dispatch}) {
    const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("hi");
    let recaptcha = null; // this will be our ref

    const formSubmit = () => {
         recaptcha.execute()
    }

    const onRecaptchaResolved = ( recaptchaToken) => {
         console.log(inputValue); // always logs; "hi"
    }


    return (
        <>          
            <Input 
                placeholder="you@example.com"
                type="text"
                value={inputValue}
                onChange={e => setInputValue(e.target.value)
                }
            />
            <Recaptcha
                ref={ ref => recaptcha = ref }
                sitekey={ "{MY_SITE_KEY}" }
                onResolved={recaptchaToken =>{ onRecaptchaResolved(recaptchaToken)} } 
            />

            <SubmitButton onClick={formSubmit}> Submit email</SubmitButton>
        </>
    )
}
```

How do I ensure that the input value read in `onRecaptchaResolved` is the updated value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`react-google-invisible-recaptcha` seems to store the initial value provided in `onResolved` and won't update it unless `<Recaptcha>` is re-mounted. See
https://github.com/szchenghuang/react-google-invisible-recaptcha/blob/master/src/index.js#L41

The easiest way to confirm this is to set a `key` on `<Recaptcha>` that changes whenever `inputValue` changes.